# How to achieve this flutter UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, camera

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpTFK.png)

This is the UI i am trying to get in my flutter application,

Tried with camera plugin but don't know to costomise it can any one provide a full code for this have been stuck with this for more than 3 days,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: do you want to crop the image in circular?  or just want an ui that show brighter inside the circle?

Comment: @mageshmagi Yes i want the UI like i provided and capture the image within the circle UI thats my need

Comment: @ShahbasAhsanKK check this  https://pub.dev/packages/crop_your_image package this will do. also i added answer check for sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this package to achieve both the ui and to crop circular [crop_your_image](https://pub.dev/packages/crop_your_image)

sample code

```
 Crop(
     controller: _cropController,
                      image: //Uint8List of image data,
                      onCropped: (croppedData) {
                        setState(() {
                          _croppedData = croppedData;
                          _isCropping = false;
                        });
                      },
                      withCircleUi: true,
                      onStatusChanged: (status) => setState(() {
                      
                      }),
                      initialSize: 0.5,
                      maskColor: _isSumbnail ? Colors.white : null,
                      cornerDotBuilder: (size, edgeAlignment) =>
                          const SizedBox.shrink(),
                      interactive: true,
                      fixArea: true,
                      radius: 20,
                      initialAreaBuilder: (rect) {
                        return Rect.fromLTRB(
                          rect.left + 24,
                          rect.top + 24,
                          rect.right - 24,
                          rect.bottom - 24,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

and when crop use the `.cropcircle()` method to crop the image circular

```
 _cropController.cropCircle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the third-party package like `image_editor` and `extended_image`([Github](https://github.com/fluttercandies/extended_image#editor))

You can create a new ExtendedImage with edit mode

```
    ExtendedImage.network(
      imageTestUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      mode: ExtendedImageMode.editor,
      extendedImageEditorKey: editorKey,
      initEditorConfigHandler: (state) {
        return EditorConfig(
            maxScale: 8.0,
            cropRectPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            hitTestSize: 20.0,
            cropAspectRatio: _aspectRatio.aspectRatio);
      },
    );
```

And if you want the border to be a circle, you may need to pass a custom `cornerPainter` param to the config when creating ExtendedImage

```dart
...
initEditorConfigHandler: (state) {
        return EditorConfig(
            /// Other configs
            /// Here choose a circle border painer
            cornerPainter: ExtendedImageCropLayerPainterCircleCorner()
      },
...
```

However you may need to create a cornerPainter class yourself if you want the image edit UI to be highly customized, and you can check the [github repo](https://github.com/fluttercandies/extended_image) of `extended_image` for more info.